# Laravel 5.1 - get data from database group by id and sum values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1

Im not sure how to go about this, i need to get data from a table and sum the values of each field together where the ID is the same.

**Things I Have Tried**

- Pulled all data and tried to store duplicates in array then sort it like that

`$users = User::all();`

```
   $array = [];
    foreach($users as $user)
        {
            array_push($array, [$user->account_id => $user->amount]);
        }
```

- Use laravel collections to store the array data and sort it through there

Other than that im not too sure how to go about this! Here is the data that i pull from the database.

```
0: {1: 100.00}
1: {1: 100.00}
2: {2: 100.00}
3: {2: 100.00}
```

This is the output i want

```
0: {1: 200.00}
1: {2: 200.00}
```

This is all i need nothing else I feel like its really simple but I have no clue, any help and guidance will be appreciated, any further information needed will be provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
<?php
User::groupBy('account_id')
   ->selectRaw('sum(amount) as sum, account_id')
   ->lists('sum','account_id');
```

**EDIT**

Since `->lists()` is now deprecated in laravel 5.2+ it should now be `->pluck()`, just for reference

Comment: Stress = gone, thank you if you have time could you quickly explain the 'sum(amount) as sum, account_id'? Im not 100% sure what it does also the lists if you have time, IF NOT ill just try look them up later!

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: `sum(amount) as sum` will return the sum for a specific `account_id` as we are doing group by `account_id`.

Comment: `lists()`is going to return the `account_id` and `sum` as an array.

Comment: Alright thank you this is a solid answer for future reference

Answer (score 1):

If you want use PHP to group and sum it try:

```
$users = array(
    array(
        "account_id" => 1,
        "amount" => 100
    ),
    array(
        "account_id" => 1,
        "amount" => 100
    ),
    array(
        "account_id" => 2,
        "amount" => 100
    ),
    array(
        "account_id" => 2,
        "amount" => 100
    ),
    array(
        "account_id" => 2,
        "amount" => 100
    ),
    array(
        "account_id" => 2,
        "amount" => 100
    )
);
$response = array();
foreach ($users as $usersIndex => $usersValue) {
    if (!isset($response[$usersValue["account_id"]])) {
        $response[$usersValue["account_id"]][$usersValue["account_id"]] = 0;
    }
    $response[$usersValue["account_id"]][$usersValue["account_id"]] += $usersValue["amount"];
}
$response = array_values($response);
var_dump($response);
```

output:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { [1]=> int(200) } [1]=> array(1) { [2]=> int(400) } }
```

But for that operation you should use groupBy and sum query.

Answer (score 1):

This is one example:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                ->select('id', DB::raw('SUM(amount) as total_amount'))
                ->groupBy('id')
                ->get();
```